# Сохранение значений блока "День рождения" при обновлении страницы

Tags: дата, php

Здравствуйте, есть форма выбора даты рождения, в которой 3 поля соответственно: день, месяц, год; Задача состоит в том, чтобы при обновлении страницы выбранные данные оставались в полях. Вот код и собственно проблема: не сохраняются данные поля год

```
        <tr>
            <th><label for="age"><?php _e( 'Дата рождения' ); ?></label></th>
        <td><select name="days" id="days"><option value="0"></option>
                <?php for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++) { ?>                
                <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); ?></option>
                <?php } ?>                
</select>
            <select name="months" id="months"><option value="0"></option>
                <?php for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) { ?>                
                <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); ?></option>
                <?php } ?>                
            </select>
            <select name="years" id="years"><option value="0"></option>
                <?php for($i=date("Y"), $n=date("Y")-70; $i>=$n; $i--) { ?>                
                <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>                
            </select>
        </td>
            <script>
                document.getElementById("days").onchange = function() {localStorage.setItem('days', document.getElementById("days").value);}
                if (localStorage.getItem('days')) {document.getElementById("days").options[localStorage.getItem('days')].selected = true;}
                document.getElementById("months").onchange = function() {localStorage.setItem('months', document.getElementById("months").value);}
                if (localStorage.getItem('months')) {document.getElementById("months").options[localStorage.getItem('months')].selected = true;}
                document.getElementById("years").onchange = function() {localStorage.setItem('years', document.getElementById("years").value);}
                if (localStorage.getItem('years')) {document.getElementById("years").options[localStorage.getItem('years')].selected = true;}
            </script>       
        </tr>
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё потому что:
У первых 2-х select ключи совпадают с элементами массива options

В случае с годом - .options = {1:"1970"...}
и ты пытаешься достучаться до него через год

корректный код

```
            <script>
        if (localStorage.getItem('years')) {
            document.getElementById("years").value = localStorage.getItem('years');
        }
            </script>
```